# Module 'Firebase' has no member named 'defaultConfig'

Tags: swift2, xcode7, firebase-realtime-database

I am in process with the tutorial [Firebase Tutorial: Real-time Chat](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat) and when I save podfile and I try to build and run, I have this  error

> Module 'Firebase' has no member named 'defaultConfig' ".

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where does this error appear?

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is the version of Firebase (current: 3.2.1). Chat-chat tutorial have used firebase 2.5.1.

Fix your problems:

- Delete `override init()` method in AppDelegate.swift
- Adding this line of code `FIRApp.configure()` in `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

This is my codes:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4YYS.png)

You should refer to this post: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios

Comment: I forgot one thing: You should add [GoogleServices-Info.plist](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites)